# FancyBox 2.1 - images loading limit

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I'm dynamically loading various image galleries of different sizes (from 2 pics to 200pics) using `$.fancybox.open(FB_obj,{some parameters})` with thumbnail.

Everything is working and loading and all but when the gallery exceed 60pics then here in there in the thumbnail gallery I see "empty slots" and when I click on it the error message appears "Image couldn't be loaded etc", for larger galleries with 150+ pics the +/- 30 last ones are never loaded.

Someone has an idea why this is happening ? I guess something with loading time maybe or the `PHP_MEMORY_LIMIT` (I have 256M, each pic is arround 150Kb)?

Thank you very much

Daniel

Comment: Fancybox 2 has a `preload` option (Integer default value is 3). You may try increasing this number. In any case, fancybox builds the thumbnails on the fly from the big images and with 200+ images that cannot be optimum. Maybe it could be a good idea to preload your images (via other methods like http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/preloading-images-from-a-directory/) before render them in fancybox.

Comment: @JFK Tks for the link, but I'm not sure if this could help, every pic is from a different directory. For the preload function I thought that it was affecting the amount of pictures being loaded before showing the first one... so even if I set it to 10 how it could help me for the 180th pic ? Do you think feeding FB with thumbnail pics instead of letting him create it each time could help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By checking the existence of each picture server-side (with jQuery/AJAX) I got a preloading effect and all the picture are now displayed correctly no matter what size the gallery is.

No need to change any parameter

Tks JFK for pointing out preloading